# Deleted my secondary_links block; where to find another?

Tags: blocks, navigation, nodes

How would I re-add a copy of "secondary links" to my Bartik-themed installation?  I seem to have deleted it a year ago when I didn't think I'd want a blogroll, but would like one now.

Comment: you could try [setting the the links](http://drupal.org/node/63601) again.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new menu and add your new links to that you can call it secondary links if you like. Then add it to a region via the blocks menu or with php through your page.tpl.php